# Spliting multidimensional array into another by value

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like :

```
[ ['2217', 'onevalue']
, ['1694', 'twovalue']
, ['2852', 'twovalue']
, ['1994', 'threevalue']
, ['1258', 'onevalue']
, ['1710', 'onevalue']
, ['2348', 'threevalue']
, ['2009', 'threevalue']
, ['3655', 'threevalue'] ]
```

Now I want to split this data into three arrays based on the second element of each pair, e.g.:

```
onevalue = [['1258', 'onevalue'],['1710', 'onevalue'],['2217', 'onevalue']]
twovalue = [['1258', 'twovalue'],['1710', 'twovalue'],['2217', 'twovalue']]
threevalue = [['1258', 'threevalue'],['1710', 'threevalue'],['2217', 'threevalue']]
```

Can you help me with a hint on how to do that in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
arr = [['2217' , 'onevalue'],
['1694' , 'twovalue'],
['2852' , 'twovalue'],
['1994' , 'threevalue'],
['1258' , 'onevalue'],
['1710' , 'onevalue'],
['2348' , 'threevalue'],
['2009' , 'threevalue'],
['3655' ,'threevalue']]

dic = {}
for item in arr :
    if item[1] in dic :
        dic[item[1]].append(item)
    else :
        dic[item[1]] = [item]


for name,value in dic.items() :
    exec(f"{name} = {value}")

print(onevalue)
print(twovalue)
print(threevalue)
```

Comment: +1 for using the f-form ) although I'd probably write `{value}` as `{value!r}` just in case we'd want to extend this code in the future ; ( ps. and as it could be just a little too much for a person asking help with their first Python steps -- adding some comments probably wouldn't hurt, what do you think? )

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a set of keys, in your case {onevalue, twovalue}. For each iteration through the main loop, check if the 'onevalue', 'twovalue' part is present in the set, if yes, then add to its corresponding array.

Otherwise, create a new array for the same, add the full element ['num', 'type-value'] and then add the new type-value into your set. You're set!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
    temp = dict()
    for i in input_data:
        if i[1] in temp:
            temp[i[1]].append(i)
        else:
            temp[i[1]] = [i]

    for obj in temp.keys():
        print(temp[obj])

# [['2217', 'onevalue'], ['1258', 'onevalue'], ['1710', 'onevalue']]
# [['1694', 'twovalue'], ['2852', 'twovalue']]
# [['1994', 'threevalue'], ['2348', 'threevalue'], ['2009', 'threevalue'], ['3655', 'threevalue']]
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try this one:

```
myList = [
    ['2217', 'onevalue'],
    ['1694', 'twovalue'],
    ['2852', 'twovalue'],
    ['1994', 'threevalue'],
    ['1258', 'onevalue'],
    ['1710', 'onevalue'],
    ['2348', 'threevalue'],
    ['2009', 'threevalue'],
    ['3655', 'threevalue']
]

onevalue = []
twovalue = []
threevalue = []
for x in myList:
    if x[1] == 'onevalue':
        onevalue.append(x)
    elif x[1] == 'twovalue':
        twovalue.append(x)
    elif x[1] == 'threevalue':
        threevalue.append(x)

print(onevalue)
print(twovalue)
print(threevalue)
```